PubSub subscriptions across Google project
I have a Pubsub topic say top1 in proj1 with a subscription that already exists, and its fully qualified name is proj1/subscriptions/sub1
I have a service account in a different project proj2 and this account is called sa2. sa2 was granted the following permissions

roles/pubsub.editor
roles/pubsub.publisher
roles/pubsub.subscriber

I went ahead and created a new subscription on top1 in proj1 using the cli and creds of sa2 and let us call it proj2/subscriptions/sub2.
Everything works fine when I try to use JAVA SDK and consume from proj2/subscriptions/sub2 as top1 in proj1 has this new subscription that I created.
However, I do not in long run want to create a subscription. I want to use an existing subscription in the other project ie proj1/subscriptions/sub1 with sa2. But when I try that with above permissions granted, I am getting a permission denied.
Pasting just a small part of trace

com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.


Please include specific command examples and output rather than describe commands. What gcloud commands did you use and what was the output? The benefit of stack overflow is not only in answering the question for you but for others and, without detail, it fails the second test.

I suspect (!) that when you created sub2, the command created the correct IAM bindings on proj1 for you and you will need to replicate these for sa2. Essentially, the resources are in proj1 and so granting sa2 permissions in proj2 is incorrect. You want to grant sa2 permissions in proj1 (where the resources live). You can try gcloud projects get-iam-policy proj1 and same-same for proj2 and ensure that sa2 has the correct subset of permissions as sa1
